# How to calculate the residue of $1/f(z)$ at a numerical approximation to a root of $f(z)$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, evaluation, number-theory

The input

```
Residue[1/DirichletL[19,10,s],{s,s0}]
```

gives `0` even when `s0` is a root. For example, from LMFDB, I found `s0 = 0.5 + 1.51608375316006 I` is an approximate root of `DirichletL(19,10,s)`. (In LMFDB this character is actually indexed 18, though.)

For the Riemann zeta function, we can get around this by using `ZetaZero[1]` to represent `s0`. What can be done for other $L$-functions?

Comment: what is LMFDB?....from help it says about Residue `Laurent expansion of expr`. What is the Laurent expansion of `1/DirichletL[19,10,s]`? does it have a Laurent expansion?

Comment: LMFDB is a database of information about $L$-functions and related structures: http://www.lmfdb.org/. `DirichletL[19,10,s]` is a specific $L$-function, $L(\chi,s)$, where the modulus of the Dirichlet character $\chi$ is $19$. It has a simple zero at `s0`, so it's reciprocal should have a pole there (and therefore a Laurent expansion).

Comment: [This](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/laurentseries/LaurentSeriesMod/Links/LaurentSeriesMod_lnk_5.html)...and [this](http://www.phys.washington.edu/~sharpe/228/notes/Laurent.nb.pdf).. might be of help. You can calculate the steps manually to gain better understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Cauchy's theorem.

Define the approximate zero of your function :

```
zero = FindRoot[DirichletL[19, 10, s], {s, 0.5 + I}][[1, 2]]
(* 0.5 + 1.51608 I *)
```

`Series` will not consider this a pole of `1/DirichletL[19, 10, s]` and I think this is why you get a zero residue.

However, integrating on a small square around that pole one finds :

```
Table[{eps, 
       NIntegrate[1/DirichletL[19, 10, s], 
         {s, zero + eps (1+I), zero + eps (-1+I), zero + eps (-1-I), 
             zero + eps (1-I), zero + eps (1+1 I)}]/(2 Pi I)}, 
 {eps, 10^Range[0., -5, -1] }]
```

[image]

Same for the `Zeta` function as a check :

```
Residue[1/Zeta[s], {s, ZetaZero[1]}] // N
(* 1.2451 - 0.198218 I *)

Table[{eps, 
       NIntegrate[1/Zeta[s], 
         {s, ZetaZero[1] + eps (1+I), ZetaZero[1] + eps (-1+I), 
             ZetaZero[1] + eps (-1-I), ZetaZero[1] + eps (1-I), 
             ZetaZero[1] + eps (1+I)}]/(2 Pi I)}, 
{eps, 10^Range[0, -5, -1] }]
```

[image]

Comment: Good method for a numerical solution. But it is possible to get the residue as a symbolic expression (as a function of s0) ?

Comment: For example for ZetaZero[1] we have the residue 1/Derivative[1][Zeta][ZetaZero[1]]. But in general ?

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec I don't know; unlike for the `Zeta` function, there is no symbolic expression of the zeros for `DirichletL`.